# UITableView became unclickable somehow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview

I had a working UITableView whose cells are populated with a title, subtitle, and image that was working great and could be clicked on to print something to the console.

In changing other aspects of the app, I or my partner must have somehow messed something up because the table view will still come up when the correct button is touched and gets populated with image and titles as before, but it has become completely unresponsive.

The tiles won't turn blue when clicked, nothing is printed, and the table view won't even scroll when dragged so it's like the is completely unresponsive to all touch events.

I've tried and tried to find out what happened but no luck... Are there any common mistakes or connections I could be missing that would cause this?

Comment: Are you sure that your app isn't just crashing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sorry I didn't see your comment. It turns out it was just a rookie mistake that Bjorn suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IB and check if `User Interaction enabled` is checked. It must be enabled. If you're creating the TV from code, set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`

Comment: Sure enough, user interaction enabled was not checked. Thanks so much! Out of curiosity, is there something you can change in code(besides setting the userinteraction enabled) that would cause xcode to uncheck that box, perhaps at build, because I certainly don't remember going anywhere near it in the last day, and the tableview worked earlier.

Comment: Since now I've never came across that it got unchecked magically. Maybe you just unchecked it unintentionally while editing properties in IB. Are you using Xcode 4?